# Is There a Command In Node.js to See My Current Directory?

Tags: node.js

New To Node.js and I'm testing it out.  Is there a command to see my current directory I am in?

Comment: Just FYI, reading this question, I assumed you were asking for a way to see the list of files and directories in the current directory.

Comment: Yes...you are correct...perhaps I should of stated present working directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's where `process.cwd()` will come into play for you: http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd